# how to route with meta data in vue route

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I am using `vue-router` to route my app.I want to route with some meta data.I have this in my index.js for route config.

```js
  {
      path: '/column/:id',
      name: 'columnDetail',
      meta: {
        specialColumnName: "hello"
      },
      component: () => import('../views/SpecialColumnDetailPage/specialColumnDetailPage.vue'),
    },
```

I use this method to navigate to `/column/:id`.

```js
 router.push({
    path: `column/${specialColumnId}`,
    meta: {
      specialColumnName: 'test',
      hello: 'world',
    },
  });
```

But when I want to get `specialColumnName` in specialColumnDetailPage component.I always get `hello` instead of `test`.I want to pass `specialColumnName` to component when I navigate to specialColumnDetailPage compnent.
here is the log of `router.currentRoute.value.meta`.
[image]

Comment: Meta data is read only. Maybe you can use props? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components

Comment: can you give me a example to achieve my goal?

Comment: I have try this method,but I can only get the `id` in  '/column/:id'.How can I get something else?

Comment: I am sorry, I understand the props is not what you need. I have written a short answer for you how you can use query to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In a route you can provide `props` property. If it's `true` it will pass the router params as props to your route's component. But you can provide a function and return anything you want!:

```
    props: route => {

        // any logic, usually parsing the route's params

        return {
           id: route.params.specialColumnId,
           specialColumnName: 'test',
           hello: 'world'
      };

    },
```

For futher reference read the documentation:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Answer (score 0):

Since meta data is read only, this will not work. You can use query params for this. I think query params are not very wel documented, may be because the usage is fairly straight forward.

With query, you add `?specialColumnName=test&hello=world` to the url you are routing to, like:

```
router.push({
    path: `column/${specialColumnId}`,
    query: {
      specialColumnName: 'test',
      hello: 'world',
    },
});
```

In your component you can use `route.query` to access the query object.

I would also advise you to use [named routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html) instead of path, see the advantages on the linked page.